# Connecting VPNC

Tags: vpn

I have installed VPNC and Network-Manager-VPNC in Ubuntu x64 and entered the configuration information like Group name, Username under VPN tab and DNS server, Search domains under IPv4 settings. I also added the values like Address and Netmask to the Routes.

Under Transport and Security, I left everything as default. Then I followed this link [using-vpnc-command-line-vpn-client](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/using-vpnc-command-line-vpn-client) to start the VPNC but failed.

So at first, I tried to copy the `default.conf` to a new file named `lullavpn.conf` using the command:

```
cp /etc/vpnc/default.conf lullavpn.conf
```

but it says:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/etc/vpnc/default.conf’: Permission denied
```

when I try changing directory to by using:

```
cd /etc
```

and then again

```
cd /vpnc
```

it says:

```
Permission denied
```

*Question*:

So first of all, how do I access VPNC file and secondly, how do I connect and disconnect from VPN?

Comment: You need to use `sudo`

Comment: @roaima Yes, I used "sudo vpnc" for connecting to the vpn but it prompts for my Password, IPSec gateway address, IPSec ID, IpSec Secret and Username for the gateway address.

Comment: You need to tell `vpnc` what the configuration file is that you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your ownership,

if you type `ls -la vpnc` it probably looks like:

```
drwx------   ...  vpnc
```

you want:

```
drwxr-xr-x   ...  vpnc
```

so type `chmod +rx vpnc`

Comment: Or you could just directly edit the config file via `sudo nano /etc/vpnc/default.conf`